# How can i serve html files from diff directory in django

Tags: python, django

I need to make an app where i have the ready made standalone html templates avaialbe in my

`app/ready_templates/template1`

Now i have made an view where i display the name , thumbnail of that template to show to users

But there is demo link there which i want tthem to see the whole template.

basically if they click on demo then  i want to redirect them to

`template1/index.html` so they can see all the templates images , js etc without linking anything to django views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your requirement seems pretty straightforward. You can do this using the [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) feature in Django. Basically whenever you have a bunch of static content like html, css, js images you put it in a folder in your app called `static`. For example the admin app that ships with Django has all it's static content in `django/contrib/admin/static`. Then you could place something simple like the below into your django template to link to the static content. You of course don't have to hard code each name like template1 you could have it dynamically generated in your django template.

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}
<a href="{% static "template1/index.html" %}" />template1</a>
```

Comment: so u mean in my app i copy templates like  `app/static/template1` , `app/static/template2`. and then they will be automatically served from there. now there will more html files in template like aboutu.html , conatct.html. will also be served from there

Comment: thats correct. if they are static content they should be placed in static. if they are dynamic django templatesthen thats another story